# php - How to upload huge CSV file to SQLite format file without HTTP request timeout?

Tags: php, sqlite, csv, server

How to upload huge CSV file to SQLite format file without HTTP request timeout?

I found a problem when I upload CSV file that contains **> 50,000 rows** and each row contains 4 columns.

It seems file uploading was successful but for only first 10,xxx rows only after that it stop working.

So, I expected it might be happen from HTTP request timeout or not?

However, I already put `function set_time_limit(0);` and `ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');` to a file, but it can't help to upload more than 10,xxx.

Note: I'm using a shared hosting server for a website

Comment: On shared hosting environments it is common to kill scripts after some time, you should check how long it is allowed to run on your hosting's company wiki / faq.

Comment: check for script time out and if you can't change  .. split the file  ..

Comment: How are you inserting the data to sqlite? Looping with one insert statement per row or multi insert queries? That can affect the speed of your script quite a lot as awell.

Comment: Thank you, I ready set time limit to 0 for unlimited timeout right now. I'm using Hostnine and don't know how long they allowed to run a script.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I inserting by PHP uploading to SQLite as text file.